# How to speed up sluggish Eclipse editors

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse editor performance has been getting incredibly sluggish for me. Scrolling a few lines can take 30 seconds, and typing text can take several seconds per character. It's driving me nuts, and seems to effect all the plugins (basic text editor, PyDev, XML Schema editor, Java, etc). How do I fix this?

I read about modifying my eclipse.ini to increase available memory parameters. I have 8 GB of total system memory, and even with Eclipse really dragging, I find not even half of my memory is in use.

My current eclipse.ini is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

Note, most are the defaults and all I specifically added was `-Xms1024m` and `-Xmx1024m`.

Are there any problems with my configuration? What else can I do to increase performance?

Comment: When did this begin happening? Do you have very large libraries loaded or lots of project dependencies? Do you have lots of plugins enabled? Are you using custom code formatting/coloring? Are you using a particular SDK? Because I've run Eclipse on lots of different machines with far less memory, and I've never experienced much sluggishness from either the Aptana PHP/JS perspectives or the Java perspective with GPE.

Comment: Also, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660247/hints-to-improve-eclipse-performance) is probably relevant. And you might try using TPTP to profile your various Eclipse plugins to see which ones are hogging memory (or if that's even the problem).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté, It's really always happened to some extent. Seems to grow worse the longer I have Eclipse open.

Comment: That sounds like a memory leak. You might be able to use Memory Analyzer ([MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)) to see which plugin is the culprit.